# Screen looks blurry after a scene change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If the scene is loaded without scene change it look fine, but after the scene change it look blurry.
Tried changing colour of lighting, but it just made the scene a bit whither.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL9Fd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2TuX.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class scenechange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void sceneload ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by going to:

Window -> Rendering -> Lighting

[image: Lighting Panel]

Click Environment, and change Environment Lighting Source to Gradient or Color.
Sometimes the Skybox value, which is setted by default, gets bugged when changing the scene.

[image: Lighting Source]